# I'm trying to make an image draggable but whenever I resize the height and width it stops working

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

So I'm trying to make a photobook for my class project. I want the photos to be able to be draggable and moved across the webpage. I was able to make one of my images draggable, but the image is way too large so I resized it in css.

However, whenever I resized it the draggable function stopped working. So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
<body>
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
<div id="resizeableDiv" class="ui-widget-content">

<div id="img1">
<img src="imgs/alexa.jpg">
</div>
</body>

<script>
$(function() {
$("resizableDiv").resizable();
});

$( function() {
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
} );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

I think you're making it more complex than is needed. I would advise the following example:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".resize").resizable({
    handles: "ne, nw, se, sw",
    aspectRatio: true
  });
  $(".ui-resizable-handle-se").removeClass("ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se");
  $(".drag").draggable();
});
```

```css
.resize img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.ui-resizable-handle {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="div-1" class="drag resize edit-image ui-widget-content">
  <img src="//i.imgur.com/KcxrVPk.jpg">
</div>
```

If you do not like the extra handles, you do not have to use them. In this example, you are dragging and resizing just one `<div>` element. I opted to use the class selector so that the code is a bit more portable. So you can have many images that can be dragged and resized.

You may also consider not using an `<img>` element inside the `<div>`. in this case, you would use CSS to set the `background-image` property to the image image in question. Something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".edit-image").each(function(ind, el) {
    var imgSrc = $(el).data("src");
    var img = $("<img>", {
      src: imgSrc,
      style: "display: none;"
    }).appendTo("body");
    $(el).css({
      "background-image": "url('" + imgSrc + "')",
      width: img.width(),
      height: img.height()
    });
    img.remove();
  });

  $(".resize").resizable({
    handles: "ne, nw, se, sw",
    aspectRatio: true,
    resize: function(e, ui) {
      var w = ui.size.width,
        h = ui.size.height;
      $(this).css("background-size", w + "px " + h + "px");
    }
  });

  $(".drag").draggable();
});
```

```css
.resize img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.edit-image {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.ui-resizable-handle {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="div-1" class="drag resize edit-image ui-widget-content" data-src="//i.imgur.com/KcxrVPk.jpg">
</div>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a `#` in your selector, and missed some `</div>` tags:

```
<body>
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
<div id="resizeableDiv" class="ui-widget-content"></div>

<div id="img1">
<img src="imgs/alexa.jpg">
</div>
</body>

<script>
  $(function () {
      $("#resizableDiv").resizable();
  });

  $(function () {
      $("#draggable").draggable();
  });
</script>
```

That should do the trick.